# How to match array length and index length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to combine two numerical columns into a single dataset which I'd like to save as .csv file.

It's the titanic dataset actually from Kaggle.

First, I've merged the train and test dataset for feature engineering as:

```
split = len(train)
data =  pd.concat(objs=[train, test], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then I splitted them for a model training:

```
#Split data
train = data[:split]
test = data[split:]

#Get variables for a model
x = train.drop(["Survived", "PassengerId"], axis=1)
y = train["Survived"]

#Do train data splitting
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.22, random_state=101)
```

And now, I want to generated a submission file which I've tried as:

```
Id = test['PassengerId']
pred = vc.predict(X_test)

output = pd.DataFrame({
   'PassengerId' : Id, 
   'Survived': pred 
})

output.to_csv('~/Documents/Titanic/submission.csv', index=False)
```

...whih returns the error as in the title:

> array length 195 does not match index length 418

for the third line

> " 'Survived': pred "

I've tried to use pd.concat().reset_index() instead of the DataFrame but that yielded TypeError "cannot concatenate object of type """.

Maybe I'm looking at it too long now, but can't really see the problem.
Thanks if somebody else can, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've solved the problem anon, so I'll answer my question.

The solution is:

```
Id = test['PassengerId']
pred = vc.predict(X_test)

output = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(Id), pd.DataFrame(pred)], axis=1)

output.to_csv('~/Documents/Titanic/submission.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Cheers.